# Add .aspx file via REST

Tags: rest, api

I'm able to add a .txt file to my Sharepoint library by posting to this URL:

`https://my_subdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/my_path/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/my_path/Pages')/Files/add(url='my_text_file.txt',overwrite=true)`

...but when `my_text_file.txt` is replaced with `my_page.aspx`, the server responds with the error:

`"error": {
  "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
  "message": {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
  }
}`

I believe I have all of the permissions a user can have, so I ask:

1. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
2. Should I believe the error message - is this really a permissions issue?
3. Is there a way for me to determine what permissions I have via REST?

Thank you!

SharePoint docs page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx

Comment: Thinking out loud: Could it be the Publishing Feature taking control once an aspx file is created. What happens on a non-publishing (Team) site? Can you rename your .txt file to other extensions?

Comment: I can rename as and upload other file types (.docx, .pdf...). And yes, I've tried disabling publishing but I get the same result.

Comment: You wouldn't have happened to figure this out, would you?